# How to use Bootstrap icon?

Tags: bootstrap-4, bootstrap-icons

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-icons.css">`

**My HTML**

`<a href="index.php" class="btn btn-outline-dark col-1"><i class="bi bi-alarm-fill"></i></a>`

I want to use Bootstrap icon inside `<a>` tag. In response getting **[]** (square).

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your html file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.5.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
```

then you can use icons like this:

```
<i class="bi bi-search"></i>
```

Comment: Thank you for response. I just have to change the path in ``bootstrap-icons.css``.

Answer (score 0):

**Solved**

Everything was OK. Just need to change path in `bootstrap-icons.css`

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "bootstrap-icons";
  src: url("bootstrap-icons.woff2?856008caa5eb66df68595e734e59580d") format("woff2"),
url("bootstrap-icons.woff?856008caa5eb66df68595e734e59580d") format("woff");
}
```